# Perfectly center button in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css, button, center

The code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#button {
appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
height: 30px;
width: 200px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
position: absolute;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Open Map" />
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure how to properly center the button perfectly in the middle of the page. I tried using left and top 50%; but that does not perfectly center the button in the middle of the page. Thanks.

here is the demo working code attached below.

[Demo code Check Out](https://jsfiddle.net/zeqLtu7t/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have done everything correctly, except a few changes:

```
margin-top: -15px;   /* = -height / 2   */
margin-left: -100px; /* = -width / 2    */
position: fixed;     /* Fixed is better */
```

**Snippet**

```css
#button {
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;   /* = -height / 2   */
  margin-left: -100px; /* = -width / 2    */
  position: fixed;     /* Fixed is better */
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" value="Open Map" />
```

Comment: You can remove `position: absolute` from Styels

Answer (score 0):

Give the button a `margin-left:-width-of-the-button/2`.
In your case:

```
margin-left:-100px;
margin-top:-15px;
```

Answer (score 0):

if button is only element in the body to set to center. Then add input feild in to an div/span..  Then apply below css`span/div { text-align:center; }
 #button { position:absolute; top:50%; }`

If whole body need to be at center then `body { text-align:center; }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a container around to make it easier to manipulate.

This is what I did:

```
#button {
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;

    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/0gdys0tn/)